# How to fix "RuntimeWarning: Running interpreter doesn't sufficiently support code object introspection." warning when using pipenv?

Tags: python, pipenv

Every time I run any pipenv command I'm getting this:

> C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\attr_make.py:876: RuntimeWarning: Running interpreter doesn't sufficiently support code object introspection. Some features like bare super() or accessing **class** will not work with slotted classes. set_closure_cell(cell, cls)

The command runs after it, but I would like to disable this message.

I'm using Windows 10 19044.2194 and pipenv 2022.10.25.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was fighting the same issue on MacOS.  The problem seems to be when `pipenv` is installed with `brew`.  I fixed it by uninstalling the `brew` version of `pipenv`, then installing `pipenv` using `pip`.  Here are the commands:

```
brew uninstall pipenv
pip install pipenv
```

Worked like a charm for me.  Hope it helps you.

Comment: Its gone after reinstalling pipenv.

Comment: Specifically, upgrading to [pipenv v2022.11.4](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/releases/tag/v2022.11.4), which includes [this merge commit](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/pull/5450), which addresses that exact issue: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5449. At the time I'm writing this comment, the Homebrew version of pipenv is only at 2022.9.24.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I must add: the state of package management on MacOS broadly, combined with Python dependency management more particularly, is an absolute mess. I live in terror every time I install a dependency as there is a good chance I will be taken out of flow for at least a good hour or two. Is this how it must be?